# `require': cannot load such file -- rsruby (LoarError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I just used the code below to install rsruby on my Mac:

```
sudo gem install rsruby
```

Then I tried to load rsruby in my Ruby code:

```
require 'rsruby'
```

When running this I get this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rsruby (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from graphz.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Does the script with `require 'rsruby'` have to be in the same directory as the rsruby.rb file?

Comment: type `which ruby` from the directory you are working in

Comment: i get back `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: try to install a gem without sudo

Comment: `gem install rsruby` led to the following: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.`